# Outlook vba extract parameter from image url

Tags: vba, outlook

I am currently modifying the body of emails sent through outlook, by attaching an image like this:

```
Item.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody + "<html><img src='http://myurl.com/track.php?sender=" + senderAddress + "&to=" + Item.To + "&sub=" + Item.Subject + "&uid=" + customUid + "'></html>"
```

Once the email has been sent, and then opened i would like to extract parts of the url. Is this possible?

Ideally i would like to store `?sender` value in its own variable.

**EDIT:**

Basically i am trying to prevent the sender from generating a hit. If the sender opens the sent email in his outbox, sent items or deleted items it still registers a hit on the email.

I would like to retrieve the above variable so i can put a statement in place tp prevent this.

Comment: Haven't done much Outloook coding but cant you hook into this this?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865989.aspx

Comment: It's not clear where the sent email is being opened, or who is opening it....

Comment: @TimWilliams i have added a bit more info, does that help?

Comment: It would only register a hit if they have the "automatically download images" option set in Outlook (which i think is *not* the default).  If you really want to prevent the chance of the sender registering a hit then you could add the tracking domain to the hosts file to block it.

Answer (score 0):

So what is your question? Retrieving the senderAddress variabel before the message is sent? `MailItem.SenderName` / `SenderEmailAddress` are not available until after the message is sent, but you can use `Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address` (if `CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Type == "SMTP"`) or  `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` in case of Exchange.